# Jquery script not Saving in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

Actually I'm trying to save my jquery script in blogger.
But when I click on save, it says-

> Error parsing XML, line 1783, column 15: The entity name must
>   immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Plese help! error is coming in `if(w > 767 && menu.is(':hidden')) {`  line in this jquery script ---

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var touch   = $('#resp-menu');
    var menu    = $('.menu');

    $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 767 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: You forgot a bout opening brace.

Comment: thanks! problem is solved of brace, but it's now & entity mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeh ! I got the solution ,actually I have to use this script in `//<![CDATA[ -----Here-----//]]>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping you first condition in braces?

```
if( (w > 767) && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
```

Comment: it's my damn small mistake but it has the problem of & entity